# Use Magento's getUrl inside a function

Tags: magento

```
 public function getWelcome()
{
    if (empty($this->_data['welcome'])) {
        if (Mage::isInstalled() && Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
            $this->_data['welcome'] = $this->__('Welcome, %s!', $this->escapeHtml(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getName()));
        } else {
            $this->_data['welcome'] = $this->__('Welcome, <a href="">Sign in</a> or <a href="">Register</a>');
        }
    }

    return $this->_data['welcome'];
}
```

I want to know if I can use the function  Mage::getUrl('/whatever') inside this function. 
More specifically, I need to use a link inside the

```
 else {
            $this->_data['welcome'] = $this->__('Welcome, <a href="">Sign in</a> or <a href="">Register</a>');
        }
```

Thanks.

**EDIT**
The solution:

```
$this->__('Welcome, <a href="%1$s">Sign in</a> or <a href="%2$s">Register</a>',
             Mage::getUrl('customer/account/login'),
             Mage::getUrl('customer/account/create')
```

);

Comment: Yes I did, and I still am trying to accomplish this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `__()` function works like [`sprintf()`](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php). You can use directives like this:

```
$this->__('Welcome, <a href="%1$s">Sign in</a> or <a href="%2$s">Register</a>',
    Mage::getUrl('customer/account/login'),
    Mage::getUrl('customer/account/create')
)
```

The neat part of this is the directives can be used in any order, you could [translate](http://www.magentocommerce.com/blog/comments/video-in-line-translations/) the above to:

```
Please <a href="%2$s">sign-up</a> or, if you have an existing account,
<a href="%1$s">login</a>. To justify this example here is the register URL again;
<q>%2$s</q>.
```

Comment: I get an error when I add this:        Mage::getUrl('customer/account/login'),
Mage::getUrl('customer/account/create')

Comment: Ahh, I should have taken a stronger look at found the missing comma!